# view all data for duplicate rows in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, duplicates

I've got a table with 6 columns:

- `id`
- `name`
- `type_id`
- `code`
- `lat`
- `long`

The first three are required.  `ID` is the private key, inserted automatically with a sequence.

I have some rows that are duplicates, as defined by BOTH the `name` and `type_id` being equal, but i'd like to view all the data for the dupes.  I can find the dupes simply enough:

```
SELECT   name 
       , type_id
FROM   table1
GROUP BY name 
         , type_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

but actually viewing all the info is confounding me.  I know this should be simple, but I'm hitting a wall here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always use the `GROUP BY`/ `HAVING` query in an IN clause.  This works and is relatively straightforward but it may not be particularly efficient if the number of duplicate rows is relatively large.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE (name, type_id) IN (SELECT name, type_id
                             FROM table1
                            GROUP BY name, type_id
                           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

It would generally be more efficient to use analytic functions in order to avoid hitting the table a second time.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, 
               name,
               type_id,
               code,
               lat,
               long,
               count(*) over (partition by name, type_id) cnt
          FROM table1)
 WHERE cnt > 1
```

Depending on what you are planning to do with the data and how many duplicates of a particular row there might be, you also might want to join `table1` to itself to get the data in a single row

```
SELECT a.name,
       a.type_id,
       a.id,
       b.id,
       a.code,
       b.code,
       a.lat,
       b.lat,
       a.long,
       b.long
  FROM table1 a
       JOIN table1 b ON (a.name = b.name AND
                         a.type_id = b.type_id AND
                         a.rowid > b.rowid)
```

Comment: My first thought was that first query, but I didn't know if you could you use two columns in an IN clause.  I guess I should've just tried.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 t1 
WHERE  (t1.name,t1.type_id) in ( SELECT DISTINCT name
                                               , type_id
                                 FROM     table1
                                 GROUP BY name, type_id
                                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

Would do it.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can do a self join on the table to find all pairs of duplicates:

```
SELECT 
  a.name    name
, a.type_id type_id_a
, a.code    code_a
, a.lat     lat_a
, a.long    long_a
, b.code    code_b
, b.lat     lat_b
, b.long    long_b
FROM table1 a
JOIN table1 b
ON  a.name    = b.name
AND a.type_id = b.type_id
AND a.ROWID > b.ROWID
```

To make sure that a row does not match itself and each pair is only output once, I added `a.ROWID > b.ROWID`, which works for Oracle. You will need a different way to keep them apart if you use a different database.

Comment: Presumably, you want an additional join condition to ensure that the row returned from `A` and from `B` are actually different rows.  Something like `AND a.id > b.id` or `AND a.rowid > b.rowid`

Answer (score 0):

That still does not find the doubles if one of the compared fields has a NULL value.
To get those, I use nvl to relace NULLs in the compared fields with a value that I know cannot occur in that table/field.

Answer (score -2):

Just make the NULLS 0...

...use NVL function.