# How to compare two tables and mark duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table for managing a scheme's contribution with key fields such as `MNUMBER`,`MONTH`,`YEAR`,`CONTR_AMOUNT` and `RECEIPT_DATE`.

This scheme allows a member to contribute more than once each month.Recently i have found out that there are alot of duplicate values in this table and now i want to get rid of them.I have a backup table whith no additional entries and i want to compare these two table and mark the addtional ones.

I tried

```
select * from table1 
 minus table2 
 union 
select * from table 2 
 minus 
select * from table1
```

as suggested in many web sites but it is not working.

Comment: have you tried `(select * from table1 minus select * from table2)
union 
(select * from table 2 minus select * from table1)` ?

Comment: As mentioned by @Barbaros Özhan should do the work. But still you can have look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718458/view-all-data-for-duplicate-rows-in-oracle for more options to find out duplicate records in case the backup table has no role.

Answer (score 0):

two tables TO one table

```
SELECT * FROM CONTRIBUTION;
+---------+-------+------+--------------+--------------+
| MNUMBER | MONTH | YEAR | CONTR_AMOUNT | RECEIPT_DATE |
+---------+-------+------+--------------+--------------+
|    1001 |     8 | 2020 |         1200 | 2020-08-04   |
|    1001 |     8 | 2020 |         1500 | 2020-08-20   |
|    1001 |     8 | 2020 |         2200 | 2020-08-24   |
|    1001 |     8 | 2020 |         1100 | 2020-08-28   |
|    1001 |     8 | 2020 |         1100 | 2020-08-28   |
|    1002 |     8 | 2020 |         1300 | 2020-08-01   |
|    1003 |     8 | 2020 |         1300 | 2020-08-12   |
|    1004 |     8 | 2020 |         2200 | 2020-08-18   |
|    1004 |     8 | 2020 |         1600 | 2020-08-19   |
|    1005 |     8 | 2020 |         1600 | 2020-08-21   |
+---------+-------+------+--------------+--------------+

|    1001 |     8 | 2020 |         1100 | 2020-08-28   |
|    1001 |     8 | 2020 |         1100 | 2020-08-28   |

select MNUMBER,CONTR_AMOUNT,RECEIPT_DATE, count(*) from CONTRIBUTION group by MNUMBER,CONTR_AMOUNT,RECEIPT_DATE having count(*) > 1;

+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| MNUMBER | CONTR_AMOUNT | RECEIPT_DATE | count(*) |
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+
|    1001 |         1100 | 2020-08-28   |        2 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+
```